# Does Github Pages retain earlier versions of your site?

Tags: github

Obviously github is a great place for version control for software, but does if you use [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) does it keep old versions of your site?

So if I write `index.html` and a week later choose to revise it, where can I find the old version?

Comment: Related for rendered pages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143667/how-to-view-github-pages-at-specific-commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, these are saved in the repository, example

[`github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/commits/source/index.md`](http://github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/commits/source/index.md)